# Несколько случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне, отличающихся друг от друга

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть диапазон от 1 до 12, как на javascript сгенерировать, к примеру, три числа, так, чтобы они были все разных значений? Например 3, 4, 12

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: "что бы они были все разных значений" 
ваш код может вернуть хоть три одинаковых числа

Comment: Вызовите его в цикле и проверяйте что бы он вернул три разных числа. Все просто

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
rnd = ~~( Math.random() * ( 1 + 12 * 11 * 10 ) );
rnd1 = 1 + rnd % 12;
rnd2 = 1 + rnd % 11;
rnd3 = 1 + rnd % 10;

if ( rnd2 >= rnd1 ) rnd2++;
if ( rnd3 >= rnd1 ) rnd3++;
if ( rnd3 >= rnd2 ) rnd3++;
```

Иногда делал на уменьшаемом массиве:

1. Сгенерировали индекс до arr.length
2. Взяли элемент
3. Удалили этот элемент из массива
4. Если набрали нужное кол-во элементов - конец, иначе - п.1

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUniques(min, max, n){
    n = n || 1;
    if(n > max-min+1 || n < 0) return [];
    var t = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        var a = Math.round(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min;
        if(t[a]) --i;
        t[a] = 1;
    }
    var ret = [];
    for(i in t) ret[ret.length] = ~~i;
    return ret;
}

console.log(getUniques(1, 12, 3));
```

Довольно тормозной способ. Думаю, должен быть более быстрый. Зато работает. =)